# Oracle - Derived table, Inserting values into a new table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a function that will read through a list of comma-separated values within a field. The result of this function will create a derived table.

Example:

[image]

derived Table:

[image]

Now, I need to get this data inserted into a new/existing table. I created and object type/package that has all the columns from the derived table, however, I'm not sure how to add/reference this data to be able to insert into the new/existing table.

Comment: I think you are confusing **derived tables** (a query you read from) and **nested tables** (a table in a table). You want to store the query result which consists of normal columns (numbers, dates, strings) and a nested table column. You want to know how to get this stored. Correct?

Comment: Sorry, yes, a table within a table., sorry I wasn't clear initially. I was able to parse the column that has CSV data. I had to create a function that would parse this and NOT count the commas that were in between Double-Quotes. I was able to do this fine. However, this created an embedded table within my table. I need to normalize that embedded table into it's own columns. I tried to bypass all of this and use regex, however, I was unable to consistently allow nulls, as well as leave the comma list inside of double-quotes and still end up with the 48 columns I was expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions that return a nested table can be converted into regular rows and columns by selecting from the table function using the `TABLE` function. (And in recent versions of Oracle, the `TABLE` operator is optional.)

For example:

```
SQL> create or replace function get_columns return sys.odcivarchar2list is
  2  begin
  3      return sys.odcivarchar2list('355352', 'Yes');
  4  end;
  5  /

Function created.

SQL> select column_value from table(get_columns);

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
355352
Yes
```

Now the function can be used anywhere, like an insert: `insert into some_table select column_value from table(get_columns);`

Your specific solution may be more complicated if the results contain multiple columns, or you have multiple result sets, etc. Edit your question with more details about the function and types if you still need help.

---

**Edit:** Below is a full example of storing CSV values in a column, creating a function to convert CSV to a VARRAY, calling that function to pivot and then pivot again back into multiple columns:

```
create table table_1
(
    request_id number,
    service varchar2(100),
    method varchar2(100),
    request_date date,
    process_date date,
    te_suid number,
    status varchar2(100),
    params varchar2(4000)
);

create or replace type params_varray is varray(48) of varchar2(4000);

--Example function that converts comma-separated lists into VARRAYS.
--(Not tested for nulls, consecutive commas, etc.)
create or replace function get_columns(p_params varchar2, p_delimiter varchar2) return params_varray is
    v_array params_varray := params_varray();
begin
    for i in 1 .. regexp_count(p_params, p_delimiter) + 1 loop
        v_array.extend;
        v_array(v_array.count) := regexp_substr(p_params, '[^'||p_delimiter||']+', 1, i);
    end loop;

    return v_array;
end;
/

insert into table_1 values(1,1,1,sysdate,sysdate,1,1,'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48');
insert into table_1 values(2,2,2,sysdate,sysdate,2,2,'49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96');


--Convert CSV into multiple columns.
--
--Convert rows back into multiple columns.
select request_id, service, method, request_date, process_date, te_suid, status
    ,max(case when param_index = 1 then param_value else null end) value1
    ,max(case when param_index = 2 then param_value else null end) value2
    ,max(case when param_index = 3 then param_value else null end) value3
    --Repeat for 4 through 48.
from
(
    --Convert CSV to rows.
    select request_id, service, method, request_date, process_date, te_suid, status,
        row_number() over (partition by table_1.rowid order by rownum) param_index,
        column_value param_value
    from table_1
    cross join get_columns(table_1.params, ',')
)
group by request_id, service, method, request_date, process_date, te_suid, status;
```

You can run the example on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3970012f7bed6baf216629f8515874bc).

But if you have any choice in the matter, I strongly suggest you denormalize your table and never store delimited values in a database.

Comment: Thank you, Jon. I understand this. I'm not sure how to rejoin to the original table for the 7 columns. For instance, in my example, I have 7 columns and the derived table. I need everything on the same row, meaning the 7 columns at the beginning, and the 48 that are a part of the derived table. Using the table statement will give me the data in the derived table in a row format, but I need that data pivoted so that I have 2 rows and 55 columns (7 from the regular select + 48 from the derived table)

Comment: Here's my full select:
select a.request_id,        -- 1
       a.service,           --2
       a.method,            --3
       a.request_date,      --4
       a.process_date,      --5
       a.te_suid,           --6
       a.status             --7
       get_columns(a.params,',','\"')       -- has 48 rows, 2 columns (index, value)
  from table_1 a
 WHERE a.method = 'saveCobqResponse'
   AND a.params like '%355352%'
   AND a.params like '%2021%';

The return data should be 2 rows, 55 columns so that I can select/insert into another table.

Thanks!

Comment: @user3874930 Will the nested table always contain at most 48 rows or is that value dynamic? Dynamic pivoting would make this problem significantly more difficult.

Comment: ALWAYS 48. There may be nulls but there should always 48 rows in the derived table.

Comment: Thank you, Jon. I wish I could have the team alter their process and not store the values as CSV, but it's legacy and that team left 5+ years ago, so I'm stuck trying to parse this field. This, at least gives me a place to start. I have created several functions, types but was always getting results in a strange way. I will work on this and update you accordingly!